# How to checkout few files and folders alone without checking out entire source

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svn-checkout

In my project I have many folders. I certainly know I want have changes in only few files (around 15) each of them are in 7 different folders. Also, I don't want to checkout the entire source to accomplish it. Is it possible to checkout only the required folders alone?

I'll have this scenario too often for different sources. Is it possible to checkout only selected folders at one shot?

**Edit**

Say for example I have a source folder contains. 5 sub-folders. Like,

> source
>
> -- Core
>
> -- Helper
>
> **-- Extensions**
>
> **-- Themes**
>
> -- Resources

And, I want to check-out Extensions and Themes folders alone. But, I don't want to check-out each of the folders separately. I want it like, I'll give the check-out location as svn.svnhost.com/trunk/project1/source. [Then, I'll select `Extensions` and `Themes` give a single check-out]

Expected Checkout:

> source
>
> **-- Extensions**
>
> **-- Themes**

Some thing like:

```
svn co svn.svnhost.com/trunk/project1/source --foldernames Extensions, Themes
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Apart from just checking out the folders you want (which only works if you want the entire subfolder tree as well), Subversion 1.7 supports something referred to as "[sparse directories](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html)". Basically you can checkout a folder to a certain depth, and then afterwards "drill down" into the folders you are interested in.

Using the command line client, you use the `--depth` and `--set-depth` options to `svn update`. If you are using TortoiseSVN, there is a "Checkout Depth" option in the checkout dialog.

**EDIT**: To clarify against your specific question, you would first to a checkout of your source tree with depth "immediates". This will give you all your folders, but they will initially be empty. Then you can drill down in the **Extensions** and **Themes** directories by updating them to "fully recursive" depth (`svn update --set-depth infinity` or in TortoiseSVN "Update to revision → Update Depth → "Fully Recursive").

**EDIT**: The update depth can be seen as a sort of "visibility level", and is remembered by Subversion, i.e. if you do a `svn update` on your working copy, it will only update to the current visibility level.

Comment: @JasperE But, I cannot do this with a single svn command right? No matter, the above mentioned method `immediates` itself saves much time. :)

Comment: No, you need multiple commands. OTOH, you can apply this technique recursively if you for example just want to checkout parts of the Extensions or Themese directories.

Comment: This is actually a pretty cool feature, although it hasn't really suited my situation really well. Also, you cannot **reduce** the visibility level; so if you have set the depth to infinity, there is no way to reduce it (pruning) without checking out everything again.

Comment: @JasperE Thanks :). I'll write a check-out utility atleast to ease the process. Thanks again.

Comment: JesperE: The manual says you cannot reduce the visibility level, but with svn 1.6 that's no longer true: Something like "svn up --set-depth exclude foobar" actually does work now.

Answer (score 7):

I know this question is more than 5 years old, but my answer may help those who are look at this question now.

I'm using tortoise SVN verion 1.9, it has an option "choose items" before checkout. We can choose required folders / files to checkout from the repository browser.[image]

Answer (score 5):

Yes, See if you have an Repository address like:

```
https://elastik.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/elastik/
```

Simply add the folder you want on to the end. So if I only want the "trunk/includes" folder:

```
https://elastik.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/elastik/trunk/includes
```

Answer (score 1):

In the Tortoise navigator (right click) navigate to a specific folder and perform checkout against the location