# How not to download entire folder with (tortoise) SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I need to checkout from a huge repository (over 25GB in size). Still I know that some big folders will not be needed. Can I avoid downloading them somehow?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to checkout few files and folders alone without checking out entire source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032059/how-to-checkout-few-files-and-folders-alone-without-checking-out-entire-source)

Comment: Is it possible to rework your project layout? it seems your real problem is poorly laid out source.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to look up Sparse Checkouts in the [svn book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html), or the [Tortoise manual](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-checkout.html).

In short - checkout the root folder, using "just this item" option in the checkout dialog, then use the repo browser to view the project, select the ones you want to checkout and use the "update item to revision" menu item to check them out. This allows you to check out a working copy that contains only a partial set of the repo.

Alternatively, you can use the exclude option to remove a directory you've already checked out.

Comment: Folders can be selected in the first checkout, with the button "Choose items".

Comment: I know, but I always prefer to checkout just the root, and then I can pick and choose what I need afterwards. Its a hangover from a repo several gig in size, I would be work on a piece at a time as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure SVN server user restriction.

Suppose you need to get full access on your product(ABCProduct), but you are not interested on "database" folder to download.

Then you need to write below script in SVN server( you need SVN admin privilege to perform this ).

```
[Repo:/branches/ABCProduct]
me = rw

[Repo:/branches/ABCProduct/database]
me =
```

[Server configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18200855/how-not-to-download-entire-folder-with-tortoise-svn)

Comment: @bahrep This is a permanent workaround in server side only. The advantage of this approach is, checkout can perform every time directly with out sparse update. Disadvantage of this approach is user doesn't have any more access on restricted items/folder.