# Project structure in eclipse for SVN based projects

Tags: eclipse, svn

I have a single folder project **myProject** with the structure as below on eclipse

- myProject

  - src
  - web
  - test

I have a SVN repository say **ProRep** and my project **myProject** under it which looks like below:

- ProRep

  - myProject

    - src
    - web
    - test
    - trunk
    - branches
    - tags

On checking out files from the SVN repository, using the path *someurl*/ProRep/myProject, the folders - tags, branches and trunk also get checked out. Is there any way to avoid this from happening. I want only the src, web and test folders on my workspace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SVN per default adds the folders trunk, branches and tags to a project root.

So your structure could look like this:

- ProRepo

  - myProject

    - trunk

      - src
      - web
      - test
    - branches
    - tags

Have a look at this:
https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/doc/user/svn-best-practices.html and
https://ariejan.net/2006/11/24/svn-how-to-structure-your-repository/

Also this was answerd before: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032059](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032059/how-to-checkout-few-files-and-folders-alone-without-checking-out-entire-source)

Comment: Does that mean I will need to create the folders of my project within the trunk folder?

Comment: Yes, that is the recommended way.

Comment: And then I should checkout using the link someurl/ProRep/myProject/trunk is it?

Comment: If you decide to follow this best practice, yes.