# Maintaining repository directory structure locally for large project

Tags: svn, version-control

As answered in this post, SVN does not offer an option for checking out only the directory structure of a repository:

[SVN: Checkout/export only the directory structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/537234/svn-checkout-export-only-the-directory-structure)

We have a very large repository and would like to maintain just the repository structure locally to simplify checking out parts of the project.

Is there another version control system which does suit this use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really you should approach this a different way. If you are using Tortoise, you can use the repo browser to view the directory structure and if you only want to check out a part of the repo contents, you can right click on a given folder, and the resulting dialog will let you choose where on your local machine you want to check it out to.

Hope that helps :)