# Clone SVN repository with empty folder structure

Tags: svn, svn-repository

For the purposes of training new devs in our team, I would like to clone an SVN repository with its folder structure without any files or history in it.

- SVN version 1.8.10 (r1615264)
- Running on Debian 7
- I have root permissions on the VM if needed

Thank you VERY much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Possible duplicate:
[SVN: Checkout/export only the directory structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/537234/svn-checkout-export-only-the-directory-structure)

It is possible using

```
svn ls -R
```

From the first answer of the provided link (svn directory structure without checkout)

```
svn ls -R {svnrepo} | grep "/$" | xargs -n 1 mkdir -p
```

Comment: Thank you for the link and the suggestion, this should do the job!